# Sharepoint document library raising exception on files that don't exist

Tags: document-library, 2007, 404, filenotfoundexception

I've been monitoring exceptions which are raised from my site and noticed that a few errors of late - in particular an exception with a message stating that the the file {file name here} does not exists.

To give you a bit of background we use SharePoint to host content and we occasionally link to documents and store these in document libraries. It seems that someone is trying to guess names of other documents and putting this in the URL. The document names are clearly wrong and have never existed in the library - so I would expect them to get a http 404 but instead I'm getting exceptions raised.

I'm beginning to think this is a SharePoint oddity - but I need to try and stop the exceptions being raised so any thoughts? I't doesn't appear to be anything to do with any custom code just something SharePoint raises as an exception.

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.

at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Source:             System.Web
SourceId:           Website.Settings.Global.Application_Error
Inner Ex Source:    Microsoft.SharePoint
Inner Ex Message:   The file /sitecollectiondocuments/development/web documents/Pages/.aspx does not exist.
```

Comment: What do you mean by exception? Do you mean an error is logged in the event log or ULS?

Comment: Any error / issue on our web server raises an exception and e-mails it to me. I've amended the question above to include the exception being generated